# Serialize class as its one member with Jackson

Tags: scala, serialization, jackson

Sometimes the class has only one member to serialize (other members are transient), and I would like to serialize and deserialize this class as its only member.

Consider following code:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.experimental.ScalaObjectMapper

case class Content(i:Seq[Int])

case class Wrap(content:Content)

object Main extends App {
  val om = new ObjectMapper() with ScalaObjectMapper {
    registerModule(new DefaultScalaModule)
  }

  val roots = Wrap(Content(Seq(1,2,3)))

  val out = om.writeValueAsString(roots)

  println(out)

  val test = om.readValue(out, classOf[Wrap])
  println(test)

}
```

The result of serialization of `Wrap`is `{"content":{"i":[1,2,3]}}`.

I would like to get `{"i":[1,2,3]}` only. I guess I could do this with custom serializer/deserializer, but given in real case the content is a complex class, this would mean I would have to serialize the content manually, if I am not mistaken. I would prefer some more straightforward solution.

Is it possible to "delegate" the serialization/deserialization to a member/constructor parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done using [converters](http:///2.5.1/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/util/Converter.html), which can be used to modify Jackson behaviour using `JsonSerialize` and `JsonDeserialize` properties.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.{JsonSerialize, JsonDeserialize}
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.StdConverter

@JsonDeserialize(converter=classOf[WrapConverterDeserialize])
@JsonSerialize(converter=classOf[WrapConverterSerialize])
case class Wrap(content:Content)

class WrapConverterDeserialize extends StdConverter[Content,Wrap] {
  override def convert(value: Content) = new Wrap(value)
}
class WrapConverterSerialize extends StdConverter[Wrap,Content] {
  override def convert(value: Wrap) = value.content
}
```